# Update current item

Tags: list, splistitem, update

I am trying to update current items, but all items in the list get updated why?

```
 public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
        {

            SPList myList = web.Lists.TryGetList("DocumentList");
            SPListItemCollection itemCollection = myList.Items;
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

            for (int iCount = 0; iCount < itemCollection.Count; iCount++)
            {

                SPListItem _item = itemCollection[iCount];

                _item["MyField"] = "";
                _item.Update();
            }




        }}
```

Comment: You just want to update the item currently being added? In the code you are updating all the items

Comment: Because you loop over **all** items and update them?

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri Yes i only want to update the current item being added,

Comment: @TheRock use `properties.ListItem` instead, because that is the one that is being added. Don't loop over all items.

Comment: properties.ListItem is null in ItemAdding. If you want to use that, use ItemAdded.

Comment: My bad. I was reading too fast and thought he is already using ItemAdded.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify item properties, except ID like this.

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    string mycol_internal = "";

    using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb()) {
        mycol_internal = web.Lists[properties.ListId].Fields["My Column"].InternalName;
    }

    properties.AfterProperties[mycol_internal] = "your new value";

    //Update title with another column value etc
    properties.AfterProperties["Title"] = properties.AfterProperties[mycol_internal].ToString();
}
```

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/a27338c1-4a11-43f6-a270-8c6957ee64e3/problem-about-current-item-in-itemadding-reciever)

OR, use ItemAdded where `properties.ListItem` is available.

Comment: I want to modify an existing column and set the string to empty, should i not use Itemadded now?

Comment: I'd say it's a matter of preference. Should work both ways.

Comment: Alright will try it out now using ItemAdded..

Comment: Well, if you just want to clear one field, I'd say ItemAdding is much neater, no need to check in after changes and worry about versions if you have versioning enabled.

Comment: I will update i dont get it to work still using ItemAdded

Comment: ItemAdding does not support AfterProperties on a document list? Refering to this link, http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/4223/before-propertiesafter-properties-and-listitem-in-sharepoin.aspx

Answer (score -1):

In the code you have written a for loop which is looping all the items in the list. So for every item it is updating the column value until it reaches the last list item count.
Use **properties.ListItem** to update the current item in which you have ItemAdding event will fire.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer with some code examples you can take reference of one available in question.

Comment: No need to elaborate, properties.ListItem is null in ItemAdding.

Comment: My bad, Ithought you are using ItemAdded event. In item adding you will not get properties.Listitem rather use AfterProperties as follows

Comment: public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{      
 properties.AfterProperties["MyField"] ="";
}